# Powering AC Guitar effects processor with a batteries

Tags: power, batteries, ac

I am not a tech...so I must ask before burning up my equipment...

1) Can I power my AC effects processor with batteries? (Line6 Amplifi TT)
The power jack says DC 3A min. The power adapter also rates at 3A

2)if so...Would I need a 3A battery or would one with higher amps be safe? last longer?

I need it to last at least 5 hours so which option would work best? one 12v sealed lead acid or a custom made Nimh battery pack like the one seen here:

http://www.batteryspace.com/custom-nimh-battery-12v-4500mah-flat-pack.aspx

I am trying to stay small and light as possible because this will be used for street performances where ac power will be scarce.

Comment: How are you going to power your amp?

Comment: How are you going to power your amp? – Dampmaskin 3 hours ago? I am using these: https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/CubeStEXPA     They crank and the batteries (8 AA) last up to 20 Hours...they are unbelievable

Answer (score 0):

The operating manual for the product says it requires a 9V 3A power supply. In practice the device can probably handle a reasonable input voltage range around this value, but you should probably not mess around with this too much. This means you will probably need to use some sort of voltage regulator to ensure that a constant 9V is supplied to the unit as the battery voltage discharges.

For best efficiency you should get a small dc-dc converter and use this to regulate the output of a 12V battery. You can use any battery you want provided it can supply the current required and has the capacity you need.